# Script concatenation performance characteristics on memory constrained devices

Tags: javascript, html, windows-mobile

We are currently trying to optimize page load times on an memory and cpu constrained windows mobile device (the MC9090, 624mhz cpu, 64meg ram, running WinMo 6 and Opera Mobile 9.5). As one of the potential optimiztions, I wanted to combine external js/css files, but now we are observing that page load times actually INCREASE after concatenation.

Now, that flies in the face of everything I have seen and read about with regards to client side performance. Has anyone ever seen this before? Also, are there different rules for embedded device web optimization then desktop browsers?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers can download across multiple connections (4, sometimes 6 - not sure what this version of Opera allows). By putting everything in one file it forces the browser to download all the javascript in one stream, vs. multiple ones. This could be slowing it down.

Images and other items also compete for these connections. You nelly need a tool similar to Firebug's "net" tab to view the traffic and see how the bandwidth resources are allocated.

Also, see: http://loadimpact.com/pageanalyzer.php

out of date but relevant: http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/03/20/roundup-on-parallel-connections/